# How to delete complete records from all tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to delete `User` table, `Fruit` table and `UserFruitMapping` table based on `UserID`.

How can I achieve this?

[image: table structure]

Comment: Is there any cascade deleting.

Comment: @mvisser : can you see image

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/015qa.jpg

Comment: Looks like homework to me. What have you tried already? What, exactly, are you stuck on?

Comment: Ok. on the UserFruitMapping UserID Foreign Key needs to CASCADE DELETE. You dont want to delete Fruit Table.  Only on the Linking table.  Why would you want to delete from the Fruit Table.  The association is on the Linking table. Dont learn the wrong way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these answers are poor and honestly none of you would be touching my databases. You are teaching him the wrong way. Tell me why should you delete from a table when there is no relationship between Fruit and User table? You DELETE only from the HREF/link table for there is the only relationship. Otherwise your database Architecture is badly designed. There should be A CASCADE DELETE on UserID on the Mapping table.

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple stored procedure for this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Delete_ThreeTablesData
    @UserId INT
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Fruit 
    WHERE FruitId = (SELECT TOP 1 FruitId 
                     FROM UserFruitMapping   
                     WHERE UserId  = @UserId)

    DELETE FROM UserFruitMapping 
    WHERE UserId  = @UserId

    DELETE FROM User 
    WHERE UserId  = @UserId
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleteing records from all tables can be a really messy task. Especially when there are lots of Foregin Key constraints.

If I find myself in a similar situation, I prefer to Script out the database obviously without the data and just drop the old database.

Finally create a new Fresh database using the script.

**Where to find Advance Scripting options**

[image]

[image]

**To select "Schema Only" when generating scripts**

[image]